# Percorrer tabela por jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Preciso percorrer uma tabela para saber se já existe na primeira coluna um elemento.

Tabela:

```
<table id="tabela-resultado" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Ativo</th>
      <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <?php if(count($records)) { ?>
    <?php foreach($records as $record) { ?>

    <tr data-id="<?php echo $record->id; ?>">
      <td>
        <?php echo $record->nome; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php 
        if ($record->ativo == 1) {
            echo "SIM"; 
        } else if($record->ativo == 0){
            echo "NÂO"; 
        }
        ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo anchor("gurpoProduto/excluir", "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Exlcuir", ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block', 'name' => 'delete']); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

O que eu tentei:

```
function verificar_existencia(nome) {

  var table = $("#tabela-resultado table tbody");
  var nomeTabela = '';

  table.find('tr').each(function(nome) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
      nomeTabela = $tds.eq(0).text()


  });

  if (trim(nome.toUpperCase()) === trim(nomeTabela.toUpperCase())) {

    toastr.success("Este grupo já existe!", "Aviso");
    //return false; 
  }
}
```

Ao chamar a função `verifica_existencia(nome)`, não me retorna `toastr.success("Este grupo já existe!", "Aviso");` quando insiro um elemento que já existe.

Comment: Em `$("#tabela-resultado table tbody")` você está selecionando o elemento `tbody`, dentro de uma `table`, dentro do elemento `#tabela-resultado`, porém esse `id` pertence a própria tabela. Tente remover esse `table` e veja se muda algo.

Comment: Aliás, se o código PHP não é essencial para o problema, que é o caso, busque evitar postá-lo. Por exemplo, rode esse trecho PHP no seu servidor e utilize na pergunta apenas o HTML gerado. Assim nós teremos como testar o seu problema sem termos que criar uma tabela do zero. Pode ler mais em como criar um [mcve].

Comment: olha eu removi o table e ainda não deu certo

Comment: Consegue aplicar a segunda dica, sobre o [mcve]?

Comment: não tem como me ajudar desse jeito?